# When not specifying return type, dart shows exact return type for function inside another, but dynamic for top-level

Tags: dart

VSCode shows **String** for return type of **bar**, and **dynamic** for return type of **foo**.

```dart
void main() {
  bar() => 'bar'; // String bar()
}

foo() => 'foo'; // dynamic bar()
```

Comment: Also see https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/33137.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dart's type inference algorithm differs for top-level declarations and local declarations.
That's because top-level declarations can all refer to each other, while local declarations can only refer to earlier local declarations (or to top-level declarations, but those are inferred first, so they're safe at this point).

Because of that, the top-level inference is not as clever as the local type inference, but it's also decidable in reasonable time.

Write types on top-level and class level declarations. It's safer.